# passing an input variable to a stored procedure and collecting the output parameters collection and to show in a view in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am having a view with a drop down list, based on the selection of dropdown list  value i want to retrieve the records from a table in sql server. For this purpose i wrote a stored procedure with DDL selected value as input parameter and the records to be retrieved from table as output parameters.  How to do this in MVC giving input parameter value and and retrieving the collection of output parameter  values and how to show the output parameter values in a view in MVC

Comment: If you could show us what you've tried we may be able to tell you whether you're going the right direction or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example to understand a way you can implement your requirement.

Assume you have a view with a select for the states and one for the cities with this structure:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyStateId, Model.MyStatesList, new { id = "ddlStates" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyCityId, Model.MyCitiesList, new { id = "ddlCities" })
```

And you have an action to retrieve the cities depending on the selected state like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetCities(int stateId)
{
    var myRepository = new Repository();
    var citiesList = myRepository.GetCities(stateId);

    return Json(citiesList);
}
```

You want to populare the Cities select on selection of some state, to do that you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), as I will show next, or any other javascript library to build the Ajax call, you can use also pure javascript. The Ajax will call the defined action and populate the destination select (cities) with the result in this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ddlStates').change(function(){
        var stateId = $('#ddlStates').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/GetCities",
            data: "{stateId: '" + stateId + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                var mySelect = $('#ddlStates')

                        $.each(response, function(val, text) {
                            mySelect.append(
                                $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
                            );
                         });
                     }
            });
    });
});
```

This example I give to you has the purpouse of scratch the surface of your requirement, but you have to deal with the data transformation you are returning from the action, the way you populate the destination select and other problems you can face with a real implementation.

Hope that helps you anyway as a starting point.